# capture option button status to a Boolean variable

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have three groups of **Option buttons** on a user form, and I want to capture the status of each group to a Boolean variable. For instance, a frame called “Process Subfolders” contains two opt. buttons called “OptBTN_Subfoldes_yes” and “OptBTN_Subfoldes_no” which are marked in red in picture below.

[image]

I wrote a code to assign the group status to a variable called “SubFolderStatus”.
The same code repeats at the time of form activation event and opt. button change event, my question is: **is there a cleaner, more efficient code to get the same results?**
Here is my Code

```
Private Sub OptBTN_Subfoldes_no_Change()
    Select Case OptBTN_Subfoldes_no.Value
    Case True
        SubFolderStatus = False
    Case False
        SubFolderStatus = True
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub OptBTN_Subfoldes_yes_Change()
    Select Case OptBTN_Subfoldes_yes.Value
    Case True
        SubFolderStatus = True
    Case False
        SubFolderStatus = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

for the form activate event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Select Case OptBTN_Subfoldes_yes.Value
    Case True
        SubFolderStatus = True
    Case False
        SubFolderStatus = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Good question. I do believe that you will benefit greatly from posting these types of questions in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which is designed for people to post their working code and then gets users to comment and give their inputs. Just a note of Code Review, your code might get ripped apart but, and speaking from experience here, it will really change they way you approach coding. Enjoy Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `Case` just assign the `SetFolderStatus` to the `Value` of the Yes `Option Button` and this is placed into the `Initialize` / `Activate` Sub as well as the `OptBTN_Subfoldes_yes_Change`.

You can set the "Yes" Button value to True by default using the properties.

For your use you can remove the `Me.Label1.Caption = ButtonValue` as it is just to show for testing purposes.

So you will just have one line of code in each as oppose the the `Case` selection.

See example below

```
 Option Explicit
 Dim ButtonValue As Boolean

 Private Sub OptionButton1_Change()
      ButtonValue = Me.OptionButton1.Value
      Me.Label1.Caption = ButtonValue
 End Sub


 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
      ButtonValue = Me.OptionButton1.Value
      Me.Label1.Caption = ButtonValue
 End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thanks , i like your answer, it trims a few lines of code

Answer (score 1):

You could define a public Function to call from all event handlers

```
Public Function SetSubFolderStatus(OptBtnVal as boolean, boolSwitch as boolean) as boolean

    SetSubFolderStatus = not (boolSwitch XOr OptBtnVal)

    End Function
```

And the call would be like

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
SubFolderStatus = SetSubFolderStatus(OptBTN_Subfoldes_yes.value, True) 
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your effort ...it sounds  like a good idea and I'm trying to get as many ideas as possible to apply the best one